# Airflow dag, unsure of how to chain the tasks

Tags: python, directed-acyclic-graphs, mwaa

I have a dag which essentially does the business questions task for each cleaned table because of how i set my dependencies

```
run_mount_bucket >> run_loading_uncleaned_tables >> [run_cleaning_df_user, run_cleaning_df_pin, run_cleaning_df_geo] >> run_business_questions
```

I figured it should've been as easy as doing this

```
run_mount_bucket >> run_loading_uncleaned_tables >> [run_cleaning_df_user, run_cleaning_df_pin, run_cleaning_df_geo] run_business_questions
```

which caused a dag import error due to incorrect syntax, tried googling it but cannot find a correct resource to look at

Comment: You are missing a >> before run_business_questions

Comment: @subram the only problecm with that is, after each cleaning df is done, it will start 3 different run_business_questions, whereas i would like it to run only once when all three are completed if that makes sense

Comment: You can use the airflow BranchPythonOperator to execute tasks conditionally and then execute the terminal task once ..https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/operators/python/index.html#airflow.operators.python.BranchPythonOperator                               you can refer this answer for usage tips: 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77949116/airflow-dag-dependency-configuration-to-run-one-path/77949634#77949634

Comment: okay i'll have a look at the resources, is there something similar for branching for databricks operators?